# Using facade in Models issue

Tags: laravel, exception, model

I am developing a project on Laravel 5.2 , i may use facades (Auth,Request,Cache.. ) in controllers but not in any model.
this is the error:

```
 FatalErrorException in Post.php line 73:
   syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'
```

and this is line 73:

```
 protected $user = \Auth::user();
```

Comment: Can you post the entire Model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set a class property's default value like that. Below you can find an excerpt taken from the [PHP: Properties Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and **must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated**.

Since `Auth::user()` depends on run-time information stored in the session for its value to be returned, your definition is invalid. To overcome that you can set the default value in the constructor like so:

```php
protected $user;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->user = \Auth::user();
}
```